# Can somebody please explain the below output?

Tags: python, function, scope, closures

```
def closure_add():
    x = 3
    def adder():
        nonlocal x
        x+=1
        return x
    return adder
a = closure_add()
b = closure_add()
print(a())
print(b())
print(b())
print(b())
```

The output is:

```
4
4
5
6
```

If variable 'b' which holds the function 'adder' remembers the scope of variable (x=3), shouldn't the output be '4' no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: What do you think `x+=1` is doing, if not modifying that remembered variable?

Comment: @jasonharper I think you didn't get my question. read my last lines in the question. If 'b' was assigned function 'adder' with the remembered value of 'x' as '3', then why do the consecutive calls change the value. No matter where I call it, how I call it, shouldn't x be instantiated as '3' ? Isn't 'b' which holds the function is always set to have x as 3.

Comment: The last time you instantiated an `x` was in the line `b = closure_add()`.  The subsequent calls to `b()` just modify that one instance of `x`.  (There is one other instance of `x`, associated with the variable `a`.)

Answer (score 2):

Links below should provide more info:

- [Python closures](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures)
- [Python nonlocal statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt)

What this boils down to in the end in your example:

1. You instantiate two separate function objects in variables `a` and `b`
2. You invoke `a` once, it increases the value once
3. You invoke `b` three times which increases the value three times

Since the value that gets increased in the closure is defined in the method that increases it as `nonlocal`, the value is stored after each change that is done to it in the parent function, in the `x` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The line `x += 1` is modifying the `nonlocal` variable `x`. So, the next time the `closure_add()` is called, the value of `x` has been incremented.

However, also note that each `adder()` function object (the function returned by `closure_add()`) "owns" a separate copy of `x`. Which explains why the first calls to `a()` and `b()` output `4`.